# Display array elements from JSON in the tableview

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, uitableview

I create a request to CocktailDB API and get cocktails' categories from JSON output, then I add all cocktails' categories to an array.

I want to display elements from an array in my tableview.
But tableview is empty and categoriesArray.count return 0.

My code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    struct Categories {
        let categoryName: String
    }
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var categoriesArray = [String]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        getCategories()
    }
    
    func getCategories() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/list.php?c=list")!
        
        let session = URLSession.shared
        
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: Any]
                let output = self.jsonParserCategories(jsonData!)
                
                self.categoriesArray.append(contentsOf: output)
                print(self.categoriesArray) // print out an array of categories

            } catch {
                print(error)
                return
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
    
    private func jsonParserCategories(_ data: [String: Any]) -> [String] {
        var categArray: [String] = []
        
        let allDrinks = data["drinks"] as! [Any]
        
        allDrinks.forEach {
            categArray.append(($0 as! [String: Any])["strCategory"] as! String)
        }
        
        return categArray
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return categoriesArray.count // return 0 
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return categoriesArray[section]
    }
}
```

JSON structure: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Reload your table data once you get response

```
func getCategories() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/list.php?c=list")!
        
        let session = URLSession.shared
        
        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String: Any]
                let output = self.jsonParserCategories(jsonData!)
                
                self.categoriesArray.append(contentsOf: output)
                print(self.categoriesArray) // print out an array of categories
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    tableView.reloadData()
                  }

            } catch {
                print(error)
                return
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
```

Comment: let me know if you are facing any other problem ... happy coding and you can upvote any answer

Answer (score 0):

You've to call `reloadData` after the data is set. Also, set the array to empty at the beginning of the `getCategories` method.

```
func getCategories() {
    categoriesArray = [] // set array to empty
    //...
    self.categoriesArray.append(contentsOf: output)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData() // call reload once `categoriesArray` is set
    }
```

Add-on: Use `Codable` model to decode JSON instead of `JSONSerialization`.

Comment: It works, thank you! Such a stupid mistake. I added :Decodable to my Categories struct and changed JSONSerialization to let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode([Categories].self, from: data!). Please advice how can I now parse jsonData with my jsonParserCategories() method as jsonData don't confront to [String: Any] type now?

Comment: Great. Modify `var categoriesArray = [Categories]()`. And use `Categories` model in `cellForItem` method.

Comment: But I still have let output = self.jsonParserCategories(jsonData) and it says that "Cannot convert value of type '[ViewController.Categories]' to expected argument type '[String : Any]'" because another type should be passed in my jsonParserCategories() method. What should I change here?

Comment: You have to pass data as parameter not the jsonData that you've serialized. Could you please add your doubt as another post and add the link in the comments, I'll take a look and help you figure out what you need to do.

Comment: I need to wait an hour to post another question :( For now I have this problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGR7q.png

Comment: Yeah! SO has kept that cool off time so that members try these problems out for themselves until then. You need to make some pretty big changes to make it efficient as I see it. Why don't try to fix it by doing some research on `map` and how to extract `strCategory`, if not proceed with the old method for now, and post the question when cool off time is complete.

Comment: I posted a question :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62903702/swift-decode-json-data-with-jsondecoder