# Swift - decode JSON data with JSONDecoder

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, decode

I'm working with CocktailDB API and having some problems.
I create a request to get cocktails (each cocktail's name and image) from specific category. Then I try to parse JSON with Decodable protocol. But it doesn't work and JSON Error is displayed.

Therefore I want to get cocktails categories from the following request "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/list.php?c=list" and have a section for each category (display category name in a header) with the cocktails from this section.

My Drink Model:

```
struct Drinks:Decodable {
    var drinks: [Drink]
}

struct Drink:Decodable {
    var strDrink: String
    var strDrinkThumb: String
}
```

My Category Model:

```
struct Categories: Decodable {
    var drinks: [Drink]
}

struct Category: Decodable {
    var strCategory: String
}
```

My code:

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

        var drinks = [Drinks]()
        var categories = [Categories]()
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            downloadJSON()
        }
        
        func downloadJSON() {
            let category = "Cocoa" // for example
            let url = URL(string: "https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?c=\(category)")
            
            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
                
                if error == nil {
                    do {
                        self.drinks = try JSONDecoder().decode([Drinks].self, from: data!)
                        print(self.drinks)
                    } catch {
                        print("JSON Error")
                    }
                }
            }.resume()
        }
    }

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return drinks.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return ""
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        return UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    }
    
    
}
```

JSON structure:

[image]

Comment: Rather than meaningless `"JSON Error"` print the `error` instance. It tells you exactly what's wrong and where. Hint: The root object is not an array.

Comment: `print(error)` and check the result. "JSON Error" doesn't t mean anything

Comment: " typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil)) "error is displayed

Comment: try `Categories.self` instead of `[Drinks].self`

Comment: @LeoDabus No, according to the JSON at the URL it's `Drinks.self`

Comment: @vadian yes just noticed there is two drinks properties

Comment: OP would need to change  `var drinks = [Drinks]()` to  `var drinks: Drinks?` as well or `var drinks = [Drink]()` and use the drinks property of the resulting object

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a few additional changes here. One change the decoding to `Drinks.self`. Then reload the `tableView`. And return the String for the section header. Here's the code:

Decoding:

```
var drinks = [Drink]() // modify the drinks property 

if let data == data {
    do {
        self.drinks = try JSONDecoder().decode(Drinks.self, from: data).drinks
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

And titleForHeaderInSection method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return drinks[section].strDrink
}
```

Comment: just in sync with my comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62903702/swift-decode-json-data-with-jsondecoder#comment111238851_62903702

Comment: @VeronikaBabii Thanks! Try to make future questions more clear. The person reading the post should understand the exact issue that you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty clear. Instead of an array (as your `[Drinks].self` implies) you get back a dictionary (that maps to your `Drinks` struct):

```
drinks = try JSONDecoder().decode(Drinks.self, from: data!)
```

which of course means that:

`var drinks` becomes `Drinks` as well (instead of `[Drinks]`)

Comment: but drinks is [Drinks], so I cannot assign Drinks to [Drinks]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62903702/swift-decode-json-data-with-jsondecoder#comment111238851_62903702

Comment: @VeronikaBabii Yes, of course it needs to be `Drinks` and not `[Drinks]`.  I'll amend the answer.

Comment: @VeronikaBabiii don't force unwrap data. use a guard `guard let data = data else { return }`

Comment: @Alladinian Sorry I should have direct the message to the OP  I did not realized I was tagging you. Force unwrap after checking if error is nil is safe but not the proper way to write the code